# Caliburn.Micro - Value not updating after initial update

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am trying to track the connection status of a server using a `TextBlock` on my `ShellView`. The `TextBlock` updates fine when I launch the program saying **"Connected"**, but I am unable to see me disconnect from the server when I hit the **"Disconnect Button"**. I went ahead and simplified the code to just changing a string value when I hit the button.

Here is my `TextBlock` on the `ShellView.xaml`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ConnectionString, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
```

It is updated on launch of the program using:

```
public ShellViewModel()
{
  setConnectionString("poop");
}

public void setConnectionString(string str)
{
    _connectionString = str;
}
```

This method is fired after a button is pressed.

```
public void Disconnect()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Button Pressed");
   setConnectionString("Button Pressed");
}
```

I know the button press is registering because the console is showing **"Button Pressed"**. Can somebody tell me why the text on the view isn't updating after the button is pressed?

Comment: Why don't you set ConnectionString in setConnectionString?

Comment: That was it! Thanks!